# Signal Spectrum Anomaly and Interference Detection

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency-domain, interference

I am trying to detect anomalies (interferences for example) given signal spectrum data in discrete form (frequency vs power spectral density) in python or matlab.
I am trying to do this in 2 scenarios.

**Scenario-1:**
The expected normal (without interference) signal spectrum shape is given.
In this case I tried to find anomaly based on correlating the 2 signals.
Is there other methods ? and what could the one appropriate for this case ?

**Scenario-2**
The expected normal (without interference) signal spectrum shape is not given.
In this case, I don't have clue on how to approach this problem. your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is too broad, voting to close. It should be narrowed down. In short, you require a robust similarity measure, 1D methods won't do.